# What is the best way to read just the columns that have headers with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have to read sheets from an xlsx file, but some of them have useless data outside the range of interest. The name of the headers can vary, so I can't use usecols=listOfHeaders

For example:
[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrHQt.png)

At this example I would like to import just the columns 1,2 and 3, but pandas automatically import the fourth column as an unnamed column. I would like to import just the the first three.

The output is like this
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lvce5.png)

Comment: What do you mean by headers? you can format your data by using some regular expression if that is what you want. A sample from the data or what you have tried will help us help you

Comment: Please provide an example of the input

Comment: Please, add more clarity to your question: which kind of data are you trying to read (is it a csv, a variable, an excel file?). Provide some example data and what you got so far (e.g. the code you are using to read the data). Also, add an example of what you would like as a result.

Comment: It's a xlsx file

Comment: when I said headers I was talking about column names @D4NieLDev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough to filter out "Unnamed" columns (the function passed
as *usecols* is given the **target** column name (either the
original column name or "Unnamed…" if the original is empty)).

Your input Excel file contains second row filled with "gram"
and as I suppose it should be **skipped**.

So my solution is:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Input.xlsx', skiprows=[1],
    usecols=lambda colName: not colName.startswith('Unnamed'))
```

**Note**: There is no way to pass **both** `header=[0,1]` (to use
two initial rows as column names) and `usecols` parameters, as in
this case *read_excel* raises an exception.
So the only way, as I wrote, is just to **skip** the second row.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a Boolean function as `usecols`, e.g.

```py
pd.read_excel(..., usecols=lambda x: not x.startswith('Unnamed'))
```

This will exclude the columns with empty headers.

Comment: thanks for answering Arne, but I tried and pandas kept importing the unnamed columns

Comment: My bad, I had not realised the column names are filtered by pandas only after having assigned `Unnamed...` to the empty ones. I have edited my answer.